# What is gidul bonim (raising children), and who is responsible for it

Tags: halacha, words, women, marriage

A mother has no obligation to educate her children (at least according to some respectable opinions)(Shulchan aruch harav o"h  343.4 אבל אמו אין מצווה עליו כלל בין במצות עשה בין בלא תעשה: and Talmud Torah 1.14 אשה אינה במצות תלמוד תורה שנאמר ולמדתם אותם את בניכם ולא את בנותיכם וכשם שאינה במצות תלמוד תורה לעצמה כך אינה במצות תלמוד תורה לבניה ופטורה משכר לימוד בניה ואין כופין אותה אלא אם כן היא עשירה ומתורת צדקה...)

[A mother is not obligated to give her son a bris](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.261.1)

She is obligated to her husband to [nurse her children](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.80.13) (if twins maybe only one) (when they are poor and can not afford [2 female slaves](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.80.8))

a father would want to pay to have his children watched from wasting time (Shulchan aruch harav Talmud torah 1.2 התינוקות שהם קטנים הם צריכים שימור לשמרם שלא יצאו החוצה ויעסקו בדברים בטלים ובעד זה מותר ליטול שכר.)

It seems a divorced woman has no obligations towerds her children (except to give them preference when giving tzedoko).
E"H [82.5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.82.5) and [82.8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.82.8)

---

But I see that they (woman) were [punished with child raising pain](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.100b.21) (also the fathers have [pain](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.89b.4) , and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.19b.18/)),  that even bad [wives raise their husbands children](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.63a.14), and that [they even take care of her husbands children](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.23a.6) (not hers) (is "taking care" the same thing as raising?)

What is "raising children"?
What is the **pain**   of raising children?
Why do wives do it? (Why do they do it? (Are they obligated to do it?, Does this need to be discussed with before the marriage so that it will become an obligation?), Or they just volunteer to do it and their husbands should appreciate their effort).
Raising children is until what age?

partial answers appreciated

Comment: OK. Who is responsible for taking the kids to yeshiva when dad has to be at work early in the morning? Or is mom exempt from asserting that the kids get up on time and make it on the school bus?

Comment: None of your quotes seem to relate to halakha. Why do you assume there is some technical definition to what seems like the Hebrew equivalent of the English 'child rearing'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65742/discussion-between-mevaqesh-and-hazoriz).

Comment: @hazoriz Are all the points you made above held by either Beit-Hillel or Beit Shammai, if at all?

Comment: @ninamag I do not understand

Comment: @hazoriz did Beit Hillel or Beit Shammai say anything similar to, "A mother is not obligated in giving her son a bris", "She is obligated to nurse her children (if twins maybe)", etc ...

Comment: @ninamag (those are just the haloho) it will take me time to research that,may I know why are you asking?, before I decide to research if Bais shamai or Hillel said these statements

Comment: @hazoriz, if the the points you are making are not held by the house that holds the majority opinion, then i am hoping once again to provide a "partial answer".

Comment: @hazoriz when you write, "A mother has no obligation to educate her children (at least according to SOME respectable opinions)", are you not admitting that MORE THAN SOME do not hold to this opinion?

Comment: @ninamag they are all (until the line across) from the code of Jewish law (and after) that means may years after both houses, and seem to be the final law according to most Jews

Comment: @ninamag maybe they do (my question still stands)

Comment: @hazoriz +1 Let us say that there are rabbinic support for everything that you pointed out, what then is the end purpose of this? What is the conclusion you want to arrive?

Comment: @ninamag the end purpose is: clarity on what is the original foundation of the Jewish (which I believe is healthy) (view) on raising children (i only found sources on how to teach them Torah, to educate them to do mitzvot, nursing them, feeding them and hitting them, but nothing on raising them, except the above sources (bellow the line), which do not give me clarity) and how it fits in to the family (what the mother does what the father does and why do they do it (if appreciation is nessesery))

Comment: @hazoriz when does a parent's (father's / mother's) soul stop binding up with the child's soul? In regards to Benjamin, he was already married with children and yet his father's (our father Israel's) soul was still bound up with Benjamin's: Bereishith 44:30, וְעַתָּה, כְּבֹאִי אֶל-עַבְדְּךָ אָבִי, וְהַנַּעַר, אֵינֶנּוּ אִתָּנוּ; וְנַפְשׁוֹ, קְשׁוּרָה בְנַפְשׁוֹ. This is Israel, or Jacob, who suffered "Tzaar gidul banim".

Comment: @hazoriz I understand about women not being obligated in a number of child-rearing issues, but what happens if the woman is the one who brought up the child? How do we reconcile that scenario with, “He who brings up a child is to be called its father, not he who gave birth” (Shemot Rabbah 46:5)?

Comment: @hazoriz can not a jewish husband stipulate in the ketubah the obligations that he wants his wife to have? if yes, then a man can obligate his wife, for any and all those biblical facts that are not stipulated in our halacha.

Comment: @hazoriz if a woman/mother is the "property" of the man, then her obligations will not be stipulated by hashem or by halacha, but by her "owner" (her ba'al). I rest my case.

Comment: probably a separate document not the kesuba and it is the wife who needs to accept it (write it), he is her owner only in regards to marital relations and nothing else (if you know differently please bring a source)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> partial answers appreciated

Assuming that you do not believe that everything in מִשְׁלֵי שְׁלֹמֹה are all allegories, then you might also consider the following as a "partial answer" to your question.

From the pshat level, the אֵשֶׁת-חַיִל reading (chapter 31) is talking about a wife and mother with children:

> וַתָּקָם, בְּעוֹד לַיְלָה--וַתִּתֵּן טֶרֶף לְבֵיתָהּ;    וְחֹק,
>   לְנַעֲרֹתֶיהָ.

And:

> צוֹפִיָּה, הילכות (הֲלִיכוֹת) בֵּיתָהּ!

From preparing provisions to engaging in business ventures, everything that this married mother does is for her to raise her children into responsible adults.

At the same time: if she is a married mother, then what she does for "her husband" בַּעְלָהּ is also equally for her "children" בָנֶיהָ, because both the former and the latter constitutes her "house" בֵּיתָהּ. Altogether "קָמוּ בָנֶיהָ".

Her children בָנֶיהָ [from the word "Ben" (that is, at least, a male {ZaKaR}] are a Memory {ZeKeR} (or future memorials) of the Fathers. Therefore, whatever the married mother does for the children, she is in effect also doing it for the children's father (or vice versa).

They are appreciative, as well as her husband:

> קָמוּ בָנֶיהָ, וַיְאַשְּׁרוּהָ;    בַּעְלָהּ, וַיְהַלְלָהּ.

If a woman had such a mother, would not such a woman want to imitate her mother?

Does everything in the Torah or Tanakh have to begin with "Thou shalt ..." before we accept or follow certain actions as (if it were) a Mitzvah (Commandment)?

Also, in the parasha about Abraham driving Hagar and Ishmael away, it says that Hagar (the mother) looked for or took a wife for Ishmael. This answers part of the question about what a mother does, and up to how old she should care for or raise her child? In this case, until he is old enough to get married:

> וַיֵּ֖שֶׁב בְּמִדְבַּ֣ר פָּארָ֑ן וַתִּקַּח־ל֥וֹ אִמּ֛וֹ אִשָּׁ֖ה
>   מֵאֶ֥רֶץ מִצְרָֽיִם:

Another biblical fact about what a mother and a father make themselves responsible for:

In the story of Shimshon, the same thing: BOTH the mother and father make themselves responsible to take a wife for their son.

> וַיַּ֗עַל וַיַּגֵּד֙ לְאָבִ֣יו וּלְאִמּ֔וֹ וַיֹּ֗אמֶר אִשָּׁ֛ה
>   רָאִ֥יתִי בְתִמְנָ֖תָה מִבְּנ֣וֹת פְּלִשְׁתִּ֑ים וְעַתָּ֕ה
>   קְחוּ־אוֹתָ֥הּ לִּ֖י לְאִשָּֽׁה:

Shimshon said, קְחוּ־אוֹתָ֥הּ, talking to both his father & mother.

Also the next verse says, both the father & the mother respond, again showing the mother is also responsible in looking for a wife to a son, who is old enough for nisuin. This answers part of the question about what a mother does, and up to how old she should care for or raise her child? In this case, until he is old enough to get married.

When does a parent's (father's / mother's) soul stop binding up with the child's soul? In regards to Benjamin, he was already married with children and yet his father's (our father Israel's) soul was still bound up with Benjamin's:

> Bereishith 44:30,  וְעַתָּה, כְּבֹאִי אֶל-עַבְדְּךָ אָבִי, וְהַנַּעַר,
>   אֵינֶנּוּ אִתָּנוּ; וְנַפְשׁוֹ, קְשׁוּרָה בְנַפְשׁוֹ.

This is Israel, or Jacob, who suffered "Tzaar gidul banim".

Your questions were:

> What is "raising children"? What is the pain of raising children? Why
>   do wives do it? (Why do they do it? (Are they obligated to do it?,
>   Does this need to be discussed with before the marriage so that it
>   will become an obligation?), Or they just volunteer to do it and their
>   husbands should appreciate their effort). Raising children is until
>   what age?

My "partial answer" (as you requested) is:

A Jewish husband can (as accorded to him) stipulate in the ketubah, the obligations that he wants his wife (his "property") to do, such as any and all those biblical facts (that a woman in the Bible has done), but are not stipulated in our halacha.

If a woman/mother is the "property" of the man, then her obligations will not be stipulated by Hashem or by halacha, but by her "owner" (her ba'al). If her ba'al fears Hashem, then all those godly acts of women in the Bible are fair obligations that her ba'al can obligate her, by his own authority.

Comment: +1 but i disagree with "everything that this married mother does is for her to raise her children into responsible adults" it seems to my poor understanding that some of what she does is for her husband

Comment: @hazoriz if she is a married mother, then what she does is not only for her "husband" but also equally for her "children", because both the former and the latter constitutes her "house". it says "קָמוּ בָנֶיהָ". Children technically speaking (you like technical stuff, no?) are Memories (or future memorials) of the Fathers. Therefore, whatever the married mother does for the children, she is in effect also doing it for the children's father.

Comment: @hazoriz even if you are right that "it seems to my poor understanding that some of what she does is for her husband", her children still do not say, "Vay'ashruho" (to their father), but it is to their mother they say "וַיְאַשְּׁרוּהָ"! Shanah Tova!

Comment: @hazoriz while reading the parasha about Abraham driving Hagar and Ishmael away, it says that Hagar (the mother) looked for or took a wife for Ishmael. Does this answer part of your question about what a mother does? וַיֵּ֖שֶׁב בְּמִדְבַּ֣ר פָּארָ֑ן וַתִּקַּח־ל֥וֹ אִמּ֛וֹ אִשָּׁ֖ה מֵאֶ֥רֶץ מִצְרָֽיִם:

Comment: @hazoriz in the story of shimshon, the same thing: BOTH the mother and father are responsible to take a wife for their son. וַיַּ֗עַל וַיַּגֵּד֙ לְאָבִ֣יו וּלְאִמּ֔וֹ וַיֹּ֗אמֶר אִשָּׁ֛ה רָאִ֥יתִי בְתִמְנָ֖תָה מִבְּנ֣וֹת פְּלִשְׁתִּ֑ים וְעַתָּ֕ה קְחוּ־אוֹתָ֥הּ לִּ֖י לְאִשָּֽׁה: Shimshon said, קְחוּ־אוֹתָ֥הּ, talking to both his father & mother. Also the next verse says, both the father & the mother respond, again showing the mother is also responsible in looking for a wife to a son, who is old enough for nisuin. Does that answer your question up to how old a mother cares for her child?

Comment: those are not obligations but facts (the halacha is only the father is obligated to getting his son a wife,  and it maybe not biblical) and are good examples what a mother does

Comment: @hazoriz  Is it not an obligation that a father and mother teach their son, which is also taken to mean, as if they had also taught the son’s son, and so on? (Kiddushin 36)

Comment: I did not find what you are referring to,( it is a father's obligation to teach his son)

Comment: @hazoriz i am looking for it right now, while i look, you may find something here: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2835298/jewish/Chapter-One.htm

Comment: @hazoriz, there is a lot here: "At what age is a father obligated to teach his child a trade? There is no specific age recorded in the Poskim [[even up to college age]] and hence seemingly so long as one continues to support his child there is no requirement to teach him a trade at an early age." - http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/3761/ (If you accept any of these, please let me know, and I will include it in my answer.)

Comment: @hazoriz  "This serves to say to you that whoever teaches his son Torah, the verse ascribes him credit as though he taught him, and his son, and his son’s son, until the end of all generations." (Earlier, it says that a parent is responsible for the child until child is 24 years old.) https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.30a.1?lang=bi

Comment: this is all about the father, but obviously i do not disagree with these sources

Answer (score 2):

Rashi Ki Teitzei [22:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.22.15)

> אבי הנערה ואמה - מי שגדלו גידולים הרעים יתבזו עליה
>
> The father of the girl and her mother - the people who raised her badly are shamed because of it.

Comment: +1 https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Devarim.22.15

Comment: This does not answer the question, which while poorly worded, seemed to look primarily for parental responsibilities, this does not address that. Nor does this do much to clarify the term (which BTW there is no reason to assume is a specific term in the first place).

Comment: @mevaqesh it seems it does partially , (he is just lets me/us understand it anyway we want) one way of understanding his answer is , that raising children (gidul) includes training them not to commit adultery, and that the pain is when the training was unsuccessful

Comment: It is taken for granted that parents should educate children properly, this is known as hinnukh. An inference from a rabbinic source that parents shouldn't raise children to commit adultery is fairly superfluous. @hazoriz

Comment: @mevaqesh my question was not about hinnukh but giddul and that is what he is answering (my source above says that hinuch is only on the father)

Comment: @hazoriz You are simply continuing your confusion that there is some halakic category called "giddul". You are similarly willing to entertain most amoral positions, until you find a specific halakic exhortation to the contrary. Thus, without an aggada indicating in an indirect way that there is something less than perfect about a mother raising her daughter to commit cardinal sins, you think there is no problem. Take a look at Sukkah 29 which notes the imperative of properly instructing others and the punishment for failing to do so without invoking any specific halakhot.  _Sigh_ I give up

Comment: @hazoriz you gave a +1 to this answer, but it is not halacha and it is not an obligation, no? I ask this, because is it not the same that it says in (a commentary to) Pirkei Avot, that a parent who does not walk what he/she preaches, his or her advice is rejected by the son/daughter? (I just want to know your thoughts about this.)

Comment: @ninamag I do not know what specific (commentary you are referring to)

Answer (score 0):

from Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer it seems that the mother does it

[Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 14 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.14.5)

> ...He gave the woman nine curses and death:
>
> 1. the afflictions of child birth
> 2. afflictions of blood of virginity
> 3. the affliction of pregnancy
> 4. **the affliction of bringing up children**;
> 5. her head is covered like a mourner,
> 6. and she does not shave it except on account of immorality,
> 7. her ear is pierced like (the ears of) perpetual slaves;
> 8. like a hand-maid (slave) she waits upon her husband
> 9. she is not believed as a witness
>
>    and after all these, death.